# ODBC for MS Access Setup

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I'm working on getting an ODBC connection in place but would like some assistance in making sure the setup is correct.  I'm also hoping I can get some help in writing the PHP code to verify the connection to the DB is working.

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, I browse to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and run odbcad32.  (This is where I start getting confused...most pages I've looked at give pretty basic information for this.)  The DB is a MS Access file.  Which tab do I choose...User DSN...System DSN...File DSN?

Once I choose the correct tab, am I correct in entering anything for the Data Source Name?  (For instance, even though the file is 'it.accdb', can I put name the data source 'Employees'?  'Employees.accdb'?  Or does it have to match the actual file name?

Finally, what would the PHP code be to connect to the DB?  The DB is currently D:\Temp\IT.accdb.  I've got the ODBC currently configured in the System DSN tab with a Data Source Name of 'Employees' and pointing to the DB.  I've tried the following code:

```
<?php
$dbName = "Employees";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
   die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

I've tried changing $dbName to be a variety of things but everything I've tried results in not finding the database file.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is the PHP script running on the same computer as the database?

Comment: The live database is on a remote virtual server (Windows Server 2008 R2).  I created a test database that I've been moving to different locations in an attempt to get a successful connection.  I'd prefer to leave the database in it current location if at all possible.  But I'll move the live database to a local location if I can't connect to it remotely.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: Will your PHP code be running on the same Windows Server 2008 R2 machine where the Access database file resides? If not, will it be running on some other Windows box? If so, will the PHP code be running as a 32-bit process or a 64-bit process? It seems that the database file is an .accdb; is that correct?

Comment: The PHP code would be running on one Windows Server 2008 R2 computer...a physical machine.  The database would reside on a virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 system.  The PHP code would be running in a 32-bit process.  Yes...the database is an .accdb file.  If the database absolutely needs to reside on the same system where the PHP code is running, that can happen; but I would prefer to have it located remotely.  One other thing that I should have mentioned is that this is a Domain environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access an ODBC datasource across a network. You can either mount a network drive containing the database, and give the system user read/write access to it (not something I recommend); Or use an ODBC brigde, like [OpenLink](http://www.openlinksw.com/).

If you want to move the DB to the same server as the PHP code, then I think that [this sitepoint guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/) should be of assistance.

The latter one is the recommended, and easiest way, to go about it. For this you need to set up the ODBC source as a "System-DSN" on the server containing the database, naming it whatever you like. The "system database" should be checked on "none", and I recommend setting up a username and password. Then install the ODBC request broker pointing to this DSN.
On the client side you set up the ODBC client bridge, configure it to use the DSN on the remote. Then all you need to do, is to create a DSN-string like this in PHP:

```
$dsn = "odbc:dsn_name";
```

That's it.

Note that the broker does take a little care to set up, but as long as you read the guides it's pretty straight forward. OpenLink also has a trial version, so that you can figure out whether or not it'll work for you. To figure out which parts you need, they also have a [Software selection wizard](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/wizard.php).

There are also other providers for this kind of software, but I have only experience with OpenLink.

Comment: If those are the only two options available for this process, I'm more inclined to move the database to the web server where PHP is installed.  (Trying to avoid requesting money for a small project.)  So...if I have the database on the same system as the web/PHP server, am I correct in thinking I'll still need the ODBC driver setup?  If so, will that also be set up as a "System-DSN"?

Comment: I've added a second paragraph to my answer, with a link to how you should be able to set it up on the same server. There are also some open source and/or gratis ODBC-drivers, but due to the requirements we had I didn't look into them. As they didn't support our use-case.

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  That's one of the many pages I've looked at during this process...I'll take another, closer look at it.  One more question though...when creating the ODBC connection, you need to supply a Data Source Name which, from what I can determine, does not need to be the same name as the actual file.  (For instance, the file name could be "One.accdb" but the data source name could be "Two".  My question is, what would you use for the PHP code?  '$dsn = "odbc:one.accdb"'or '$dsn = "odbc:two"'?

Comment: The latter. You specify the name of the DSN, something similar to a domain name, when creating the ODBC source. This name is what you use when connecting to it, so that the ODBC driver knows which database you want.

Comment: Still not working and I'm not sure why.  The Server is named CURRY-MGMT.  One of the Server's roles is a Web Server.  PHP is installed on this Server.  The database's path is 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\IT\Database\IT.accdb'.  The SYSTEM-DSN name is Employees.  My PHP code includes $dbName = "Employees"; and connection is $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");  (Sorry...don't know how to make this more readable...unless I edited my original post.)  Can you see anything that would cause the connection to not find the database?