# Connecting with PHP script to a remote Microsoft Access database on a Windows 2003 server connected on my LAN

Tags: php, database, ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access database on a remote server to which I connect through LAN. I am making an interface in HTML with tables that need to get or add information from/to the access database. I want to use PHP for connecting to the remote server but can't find anywhere a solution. My precise question is how to establish a connection with the remote server and after that to access the exact MDB from which later I select the appropriate column to print out the appropriate data in the assigned field for. Please if someone has a solution I will appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an ODBC bridge, and to set up an DSN on your windows computer. I've written a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453036/odbc-for-ms-access-setup/39469532#39469532) on very similar question, detailing how to go about setting one up.
Adjust the answer accordingly to your PHP server's OS.